# Image-Viewer to display SVG-Spline-graphic collections

Tags: linux, image-viewer, svg, inkscape

Using `git`, I have recently installed the repository [inkscape-open-symbols](https://github.com/PanderMusubi/inkscape-open-symbols/)

It contains a lot of open SVG graphics, in many subfolders. Last time I have counted there were 77 `*.svg` files in the multi-level directory tree.

Unfortunately most of the grahics are given as spline-graphics. I think that is the term for multiple icons/graphics in a single file, located systematically on a grid.

You can see what I mean by scrolling down a bit to the embedded picture on the [README](https://github.com/PanderMusubi/inkscape-open-symbols/)
file. Using Inkscape's Symbol Panel (Shift+CTRL+Y), I can indeed browse the collections. However it is a bit inconvenient to scroll through long lists of collections with lots of similar filenames ("Gnome Icon Theme Symbolic M...")

**Is there an Image-Viewer for Linux that can display nice Preview-Images of all those Icons, in a more convenient way than Inkscape does?**

Geeqie does not work.